# Why do these two identical functions have wildly different execution times?

Tags: c

I have two C functions that are copies of each other. In the code below, I'm printing out how long they take to execute. The first function (no matter which copy it is) always takes longer to execute than the second. Why is that?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h> // for clock_t

int binsearch_old (int x, int v[], int n);
int binsearch_new (int x, int v[], int n);

void main ()
{
  int x = 4;
  int v[10] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };
  int n = 10;

  clock_t begin_old = clock();
  printf("\nbinsearch_old :: position: %i\n", binsearch_old(x, v, n));
  clock_t end_old = clock();
  double time_spent_old = (double)(end_old - begin_old) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
  printf("time spent old: %f\n", time_spent_old);

  clock_t begin_new = clock();
  printf("\nbinsearch_new :: position: %i\n", binsearch_new(x, v, n));
  clock_t end_new = clock();
  double time_spent_new = (double)(end_new - begin_new) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
  printf("time spent new: %f\n", time_spent_new);
}

int binsearch_old (int x, int v[], int n)
{

  int low, high, mid;
  low = 0;
  high = n - 1;
  while (low <= high) {
    mid = (low + high) / 2;
    if ( x < v[mid])
      high = mid - 1;
    else if (x > v[mid])
      low = mid + 1;
    else //found match
      return mid;
  }
  return -1; // no match
}

int binsearch_new (int x, int v[], int n)
{
  int low, high, mid;
  low = 0;
  high = n - 1;

  while (low <= high) {
    mid = (low + high) / 2;
    if (x < v[mid])
      high = mid - 1;
    else if (x > v[mid])
      low = mid + 1;
    else //found match
      return mid;
  }
  return -1; // no match
}
```

After `gcc test.c` and `./a.out`, you'll see something along the lines of:

```
binsearch_old :: position: 3
time spent old: 0.000115

binsearch_new :: position: 3
time spent new: 0.000007
```

And the relationship between those times is stable! The first will always be greater than the second, and usually by quite a bit. What's going on?

Comment: Consider isolating the function call from printf?

Comment: Running tests where n = 10 is going to tell you more about unpredictable scheduling and cache behavior than it will tell you anything about the code under test. Try something like n = 10^9.

Comment: the time you measure is far too small to be meaningful.. considere looooong runs

Comment: And when benchmarking, always build with optimizations enabled.

Comment: BTW, you are expecting a time unit in seconds here when your test is far faster than a second, thus the result is just noise

Comment: thanks, all; everything above makes a lot of sense. Almost too much sense. Almost as if I should have thought a little bit harder about it.

Comment: Incidentally, you could show that the speed is coincidental by (1) reversing the order of the two calls, or (2) repeating the same call twice, or (3) repeating the other call twice, or (4) running the whole lot in a loop to get repeated timings.  You would probably find that the first call is slow and the others are faster.  I recommend trying to use more than one value to search for (so different code paths are executed), and make sure you do something with the result, such as accumulate it, so the compiler can't optimize the code away.

Comment: It might also be a possibility that one of the functions is laid out in memory in a more preferential location than the other.  That is less likely to be the issue, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are measuring the time of printing as well.  You should not count the time of execution of `printf`.

```
  clock_t begin_old = clock();
  int val = binsearch_old(x, v, n);
  clock_t end_old = clock();
  printf("\nbinsearch_old :: position: %i\n", val);
  double time_spent_old = (double)(end_old - begin_old) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
  printf("time spent old: %f\n", time_spent_old);
```

If you do not count so then you should ask yourself `why does printf have different times for similar calls ?`.

Comment: You were the first to spot the reason, and I took inspiration from your answer. Have an upvote for good feelings.

Answer (score 3):

The "warming up" of all the necessary functionality to implement `print` is not-inconsiderable. Step through the C runtime library source code to see for yourself. So the first call you make to `printf` will commonly be slower than subsequent calls.

The calls to `printf` you make are within the timings, which is an error in your implementation.

Removing the `printf` call from the timings will par the result.